# Official name 'JS Array descructuring' analog in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, destructuring

In my daily practice I constantly use parentheses to structure variables in blocks:

```
[[?a,?b],[?c,?d]].each_with_index{|(x,y),i| p [x,y,i] } # ['a','b',0] ...
```

This kind of structuring variables works in methods too. Some times I use it like this:

```
def coords ((x,y))
p [x,y]
end
coords([1,2]) # [1,2]
```

but I do not know how to call this technique correctly. It's something similar to [Array to Arguments conversion](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) but not the same. **How to call technique above?**

```
# Array to Arguments converstion
def my_method(argument1, argument2, argument3)
end
arguments = [1, 2, 3]
my_method(*arguments)
```

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK `|(x,y),i|` is referred to as "destructuring" in Ruby, I don't have an official source or history of the terminology but that's what I've always called it.

Comment: In the official documentation it's called [Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).